# Can you declare and use a variable inside an XML without using XSL to transform/parse the XML

Tags: xml

Say you have an XML element you want to read in an app, however you have multiple environments where the path of dependent files may change

```
<root>
  <element ID="MyConfigFile" url="c:\Program Files\MyProgram\resources\MyProgramconfig.xml" />
  <element ID="Executable" url="c:\Program Files\MyProgram\Prog.exe" />
</root>
```

...so you would want to make a reference to the relative directory

@path="c:\Program Files\MyProgram\"

```
<root>
  <element ID="MyConfigFile" url="@path\resources\MyProgramconfig.xml" />
  <element ID="Executable" url="@path\Prog.exe" />
</root>
```

Can you use a variable declared in the XML itself to reference the relative directory path?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to add a DOCTYPE declaration to your file, declare an entity there and then reference that entity in the document body.

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY path "c:\Program Files\MyProgram">
]>
<root>
  <element ID="MyConfigFile" url="&path;\resources\MyProgramconfig.xml" />
  <element ID="Executable" url="&path;\Prog.exe" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure, try with entity

```
<!ENTITY path "c:\Program Files\MyProgram\">

<element ID="MyConfigFile" url={&path + "resources\MyProgramconfig.xml"} />
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is your question.

Comment: Can you use a variable declared directly in an XML to reference a relative directory or file path?

Comment: with entity you can declare a variable and use within the attributes