# Is using ENTITY allowed in SSIS configuration package?

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, entity, etl

I am trying to define one global configuration package for all my .dtsx files.
I have a login there:

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[SourceConnectionOLEDB].Properties[UserName]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue> exampleLoginHere </ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

This login appears in many places.
So, what i'm trying to do is to set this login into variable and change only in one place instead of do that in all occurrences.

I found [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017750/can-you-declare-and-use-a-variable-inside-an-xml-without-using-xsl-to-transform) but when i put

```
<!DOCTYPE DTSConfiguration [
  <!ENTITY sourceLogin "exampleLoginHere">
]>
```

and then change

```
<ConfiguredValue> exampleLoginHere </ConfiguredValue>
```

to

```
<ConfiguredValue> &sourceLogin; </ConfiguredValue>
```

my dtsx after start return:

> Warning: Cannot load the XML configuration file. The XML configuration file may be malformed or not valid

Am I doing something wrong? I forgot about something?

Answer (score 0):

Package Configuration files are nothing but regular xml files and the rules that apply for them should be working for this as well. Having said that to address your need of having a variable across multiple packages you can set it up as a 'Indirect Configuration' and have the value coming from a 'SQL Server' table. Here is a link that gives more detailed breakdown of how it works -

http://bi-blogger.typepad.com/etlbi_blogger/2008/05/using-indirect-configuration-with-ssis.html